# How to access elements in a PartialView (loaded via an AJAX-Call) from a js-file (working with ASP.NET MVC5, Kendo-UI)?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview, kendo-template

UPDATED --

I have an 'index.js', that script is rendered in Index.cshtml.
Index.cshtml has a `<div id="main"> *KendoPanelBar here*  </div>`
I successfully load my Partial View into the panel in main-div.

'MyPartialView.cshtml' has: `<div id="menu"></div>`

In index.js , I try `console.log($("#menu"));`

The output is a *jQuery object with a length of 0*.
'MyPartialView.cshtml' is in the same folder like the 'Index.cshtml' (elements from 'Index.cshtml' can be successfully outputted).

**As @Guillaume commented: The script has to run after the view is rendered !**

---

My actual goal is to put a KendoMenu dynamically into the div menu which is into a KendoTemplate in MyPartialView.
For getting MyPartialView, I did:

```
mainDiv.append({
            text: "Group1",
            encoded: false,
            contentUrl: "\MyPartialView"  //that successfully put the partial view where I want it
        });
```

As @Rory commented, I have to access the elements in MyPartialView when/after the AJAX-Call **succeeded**.

Therefore, I changed `contentUrl:...` to `content: '<div id="partialHere"><div>'` and tried to load the partial view into that div:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myUrl,
        success: function (partialView) {
            $("#menu").kendoMenu({ //does not apply
            dataSource: [{
            text: "<span class=\"k-icon k-i-more-horizontal\"></span>", encoded: false, items: [
                { text: "<span class=\"k-icon k-i-edit\"></span><span>Edit</span>", encoded: false },
                   ]
                 }]
             });
            //dosth
            $("#groupContent").html(partialView); //adding PartialView to DOM
            console.log($("#menu")); //even after adding to DOM, the output is a jQuery-object with length of 0
        }
    });
```

The partialView is loaded into the div as it is. But the changes I am doing to the menu div does not apply .

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When is `index.js` loaded, and when is your function run?

Comment: What do you mean by an 'empty object'. Logging that will *always* return a jQuery object. Do you mean that it has a `length` of `0`? In any case it simply sounds like you're executing the `console.log()` before the content has been loaded in to the page.

Comment: I do @Scripts.Render on top of Index.cshtml.  On document ready of Index.cshtml, the function (of index.js) is called.

Comment: Yes @RoryMcCrossan the length of the jQuery Object is 0

Comment: If you're loading the partial via an AJAX call you will need to put the `console.log` in the callback of that request, not in document.ready

Comment: could you explain us how the partial view is loaded on your page? as Rory said you might have script running before the view is rendered in the browser.

Comment: I do an AJAX-Call and I'm about to follow the recommendation of Rory

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 1):

Order matters here. Add the html before you attempt to query it.

```
//dosth
$("#groupContent").html(partialView);

// Partial View has been added to the DOM. Now it is accessible to jQuery  
$("#menu").kendoMenu({ //does not apply
  dataSource: [{
    text: "<span class=\"k-icon k-i-more-horizontal\"></span>",
    encoded: false,
    items: [{
      text: "<span class=\"k-icon k-i-edit\"></span><span>Edit</span>",
      encoded: false
    }, ]
  }]
});
```